# Пишет Unexpected token S in JSON at position 1512 при странных обстоятельствах

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

У меня есть форма динамической генерации страницы. При её заполнении, создаются объекты с текстом или ссылками на картинки. И при нажатии на "Отправить", они переводятся в строку, заполняются в textarea и отправляются через POST форму. Да костыль, но так нужно.

И так, объект расшифровывается на сервере и генерирует страницу. Было предусмотрено её редактирование. И вот тут начинается дичь.

Эту ошибку выводит консоль, когда приходит тот же зашифрованный через json объект с сервера.

[image: Ошибка в консоли]

Строка create.js:390

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Опытным путём было определено что она возникает если отправлять на сервер текстовые блоки, что были скопированы с другого сайта (к примеру, translate.google.com). 
*для ввода текста используется contenteditable div.

Ну я и решил фильтровать все, что вставляется в форму через execCommand. Теперь оно просто ИНОГДА выводит эту ошибку и в чем другая её причина - не понимаю.

Comment: Отлавливайте ошибку и смотрите что там в позиции 1512 в строке

Comment: Спасибо. Просмотрел строку через substr, действительно оказалось что в строке были двойные кавычки. Убрал и все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас Bootstrap, нужно фильтровать строку через этот скрипт:

```
isEditstr = isEditstr.replace(new RegExp("\"Segoe UI\",",'g'),"'Segoe UI'")
                    .replace(new RegExp("\"Noto Color Emoji\"",'g'),"'Noto Color Emoji'")
                    .replace(new RegExp("\"Helvetica Neue\",",'g'),"'Helvetica Neue'")
                    .replace(new RegExp("\"Apple Color Emoji\",",'g'),"'Apple Color Emoji'")
                    .replace(new RegExp("\"Segoe UI Emoji\",",'g'),"'Segoe UI Emoji'")
                    .replace(new RegExp("\"Segoe UI Symbol\",",'g'),"'Segoe UI Symbol'")
                    .replace(new RegExp("\"Noto Sans\",",'g'),"'Noto Sans'");
```